# Textview.settext() giving nullpointer exception

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

This is activity which is calling textview and getting the intent

```
package com.example.smartbrowser;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

TextView vw =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

Intent intent =getIntent();

String message = intent.getStringExtra(Browseractivity.Message);


vw.setText(message);


setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


}
```

And activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

  android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

tools:context=".MainActivity" >


 <TextView

  android:id="@+id/text"

  android:layout_width="wrap_content"

 android:layout_height="wrap_content"

 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"


  />


</RelativeLayout>
```

why I am getting null pointer exception in MainActivity.java?

Comment: have u print message to toast.maketext u must pass null value in String first of all print his message in 
Toast.MakeText(getApplicationContext(),"message"+message,Toast.length_short).show(); it will help u to doing that

Comment: u are passing values of String null which are not in actual in String Message.... so u have create this problem... i think u find his error.....

Answer (score 4):

You have to place `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` before initializing any view. Here, initialized your `TextView` before setting your content view thats why it was returning `null`.

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView vw =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    Intent intent =getIntent();

    String message = intent.getStringExtra(Browseractivity.Message);
    vw.setText(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // should be first
TextView vw =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text); // then initialize textview
Intent intent =getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(Browseractivity.Message);
vw.setText(message);
}
```

You need to set the content of the layout to the activity first and then initialize your views.

`findViewById` looks for a view in the current inflated layout. You got `NullPointerException` bcoz you initialized `TextView` before setting the layout to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You should always in this circonstance set your content view before playing with any widget as a Textview  in your example

```
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

TextView vw =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

Intent intent =getIntent();

String message = intent.getStringExtra(Browseractivity.Message);


vw.setText(message);



    }


}
```

This should do the trick :)
hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but i will answer it since this code is still applicable.

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView textView2; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main); // Change from activity_main > fragment_main
    textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview2);
    textView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (textView2.isClickable() == true){
                ((TextView) textView2).setText("Changed!!!!!!");                    
            }
        }
    });


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
<!-- REMOVE android:id="@+id/container" -->
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.thinktankcoding.androiddevtest.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container" <!-- ADD THE LINE YOU REMOVED HERE AND REMOVE THESE COMMENTS -->
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.thinktankcoding.androiddevtest.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:lines="2"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

Comment: please avoid just **pasting the code**, a bit of explanation would never hurt.